# Building an image classifier( binary) using Convolution network

Tags: classification, svm, neural-networks, image-processing

I have a dataset of images of birds and want to build a CNN classifier that outputs the probability that the fed image(test) is a bird, So that I can accept the image to be a bird beyond a certain threshold.

How should I go about training this ?

One possible way could be to have a second class of all the images/{birds} and then train a two class CNN. But this becomes a very computationally expensive task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution for images that have a defined bounding box of the bird, would be to use a sliding window and an approach similar to OverFeat http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6229.

Otherwise, you will have to train against two classes, as you well said. For ease of speed I would suggest the following:

- Use a GPU accelerated framework (caffe, torch, theano etc)
- You can take a pretrained network's weights (OverFeat, OxfordNet, AlexNet etc.) and just replace and retrain the top layers.
- Use an efficient SGD method such as Adagrad, Adadelta, rmsprop etc.